# Listening for Firepad events in Angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firepad

Just wondered if it's possible to listen for Firepad events in an Angularjs app?

I see the standard js code for detecting when Firepad is ready is:

```
firepad.on('ready', function() {
  // Firepad is ready.
});
```

from http://www.firepad.io/docs/#api

but how can I detect this within a controller in Angular?

Comment: Do you already have code that initializes Firepad in your controller? I.e. something like `var firepad = Firepad.fromCodeMirror`. If so, you should be able to listen to the `ready` event on that the same as in plain JavaScript. If you don't have such code yet, you can find it in the **Initializing Firepad** section of http://www.firepad.io/docs/#api

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't know whether there was more of an "Angular way"

Comment: You could probably wrap firepad in a directive quite easily. But "is there a library that does this?" is better suited for google than for StackOverflow. This looks promising: https://github.com/davideast/FireDeck/blob/436fa59fb65a186beec857865c156ce2ada809e2/scripts/directives/firepad.js. It seems to introduce a `<fire-pad` element from what I can quickly gather in the demo site: https://fire-deck.firebaseapp.com/.

Comment: Author of that `<fire-pad>` directive here. It's not a very good directive for general use. I tightly coupled it with an iframe to do in browser coding. However, it can easily be modified to work without the iframe. You could really just delete these lines here: https://github.com/davideast/FireDeck/blob/436fa59fb65a186beec857865c156ce2ada809e2/scripts/directives/firepad.js#L72-L80

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have code that initializes Firepad in your controller? I.e. something like `var firepad = Firepad.fromCodeMirror`. If so, you should be able to listen to the ready event on that the same as in plain JavaScript. If you don't have such code yet, you can find it in the **Initializing Firepad** section of firepad.io/docs/#api.

To make it feel more integrated, you could probably wrap firepad in a directive quite easily. But "is there a library that does this?" is better suited for google than for StackOverflow.

That said, this library looks promising: https://github.com/davideast/FireDeck/blob/436fa59fb65a186beec857865c156ce2ada809e2/scripts/directives/firepad.js. It seems to introduce a `<fire-pad` element from what I can quickly gather in the demo site: http://fire-deck.firebaseapp.com.

Note David's comment above too:

> Author of that `<fire-pad>` directive here. It's not a very good directive for general use. I tightly coupled it with an iframe to do in browser coding. However, it can easily be modified to work without the iframe. You could really just delete these lines here: https://github.com/davideast/FireDeck/blob/436fa59fb65a186beec857865c156ce2ada809e2/scripts/directives/firepad.js#L72-L80